# Google Apps Script - ContactsApp - Directory search

Tags: google-apps-script, contacts

From within the Google Spreadsheet  I am trying to validate an e-mail address  which  the user enters to one from within the domain directory.  The aim is to change ownership / collaborator rights (but that is further down the line).

I have used ContactsApp.getContacts() which has been iterated through this as expected brings up a list of contacts within my contacts.  However, does not go onto the Domain Directory

To confirm I have then used ContactsApp.getContactGroups() and  iterated through this and then used getName() which produces a list of my Contact Folders.

My question is firstly, is it possible to iterate through the Domain Contact Directory as a user?

It appears that I am looking in the wrong place, where should I be looking.

Many thanks in advance

Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that feature is not supported yet.
see also: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1822

Comment: As of September 2015, for those of you still looking, the only way to access directory data is through the Admin SDK for the domain.